# Can't plot a function with PGFPlots as it should be

Tags: pgfplots

There is parametrically defined function.
[image]
I try to plot this function with PGFPlots like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand\xfunc[7]{2*#4*ln((1/2)* 
(#2*cos(#3)^2*#1*#5*#6*#7+2*#4)/#4)/(#5*#6*#7*cos(#3))}
\newcommand\yfunc[7]{ln((1/1962)*  
(10*sqrt(#5)*sin(#3)^(3/2)*sqrt(#7)*sqrt(#6)*#2*sin((3/20)*
sqrt(218)*sqrt(#5)*sqrt(sin(#3))*sqrt(#7)*sqrt(#6)*#1/sqrt(#4))+
3*sqrt(#4)*sqrt(218)*cos((3/20)*sqrt(218)*sqrt(#5)*sqrt(sin(#3))*
sqrt(#7)*sqrt(#6)*#1/sqrt(#4)))^2/#4)*#4/(#5*sin(#3)*#7*#6)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    variable = \t,
    samples = 200]
  \addplot[domain=0:0.14,trig format=rad]
   (\xfunc{t}{1}{0.79}{0.8}{0.3}{1.2}{3.5*10^(-3)},
    \yfunc{t}{1}{0.79}{0.8}{0.3}{1.2}{3.5*10^(-3)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Expressions were copied from Maple source. All parameter variables were replaced by `#1`,`#2`,...,`#7` tokens accordingly. And for preventing known issue with trigonometric functions arguments I used `trig format=rad` option. But I got this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to maximum simplify the functions but the result was not much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand\xfunc[1]{1804.15*ln(0.39e-3*#1+1.00)}
\newcommand\yfunc[1]{893.81*ln(0.64e-3*(0.21*sin(0.74e-1*#1)
+39.62*cos(0.74e-1*#1))^2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    variable = \t,
    samples = 200]
  \addplot[domain=0:0.14,trig format=rad]({\xfunc{t}},{\yfunc{t}});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is most probably due to numerical precison of the math engine. It looks exceedingly complicated. However you have a lot of redundant operations such as square roots can be grouped and logarithms can be combined. Also pgfplots understands scientific notation such as `3.5e-3` which would also save some precision.

Comment: I have tried to simplify my example without result. See edited post.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not exactly an answer, but a comment with an image.*

I think the problem is the precision of *TeX*. One way to circumvent this would be to use *Lua* for the math calculation, which could be done by adding `compat=1.12` (or a higher level) to your preamble and compiling with LuaLaTeX. Is this an option?

(This still is not the result you are expecting I guess, because the plot does not start at (0,0), but that hopefully just comes from a typo in the parameters so something other rather trivial.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the Lua backend for
        % calculation of the functions
        % (which of course only works when you are compiling with LuaLaTeX)
        compat=1.12,
        % define some functions we want to calculate using LuaLaTeX
        /pgf/declare function={
            f(\x) = 1804.15*ln(0.39e-3*\x+1.00);
            g(\x) = 893.81*ln(0.64e-3*(0.21*sin(0.74e-1*\x) + 39.62*cos(0.74e-1*\x))^2);
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        samples=201,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
    ]
        \addplot [domain=0:0.14,trig format=rad] ({f(x)},{g(x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't compile with LuaLaTex your example right now but have found solution of my issue. I export plot data from Maple to data file and then `\addplot` from  file.

Comment: That would have been my recommendation, if data are already available from another calculation program.